# Yii Form on update not working fine but working fine in create

Tags: php, sql, database, yii

I'm using `Yii` framework, I created a new field in database for dropdown, when I create a record it works fine.

But when I update any record then the new field is empty! why?

Comment: Please edit your question to include example code of what you have so far and where things are going wrong for you.

Comment: Did you add ['your_attribute', 'safe'] in rules?